# Measuring network performance

Tags: networking, performance, bandwidth

On any computer that has a web browser that supports flash, one can use SpeedTest.net as a crude way to measure network performance.

It gives tree very important numbers.  Ping time, sustained upload speed and sustained download speed to a menu of different hosts around the world.

Is there a method to get the same information given that you have access to only one *nix box?

I know that one can run ttcp or wget if you have access to *two* machines (say, one in NYC and another in LA or whatever).  I know you can run ping to get the ping (obviously) but is there a way to do something like speedtest.net against a list of reference servers?

Best I can come up with is running wget or curl against a large file...

Comment: What sort of control would you have over the servers? There are several options such as iperf (which is what speedtest.net uses) and SNMP. There are also better methods of using ping to look for not only latency, but jitter as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can youse "iperf" with a public server like [this](http://noc.greatplains.net/measurement/iperf.php)

Comment: I believe there is a GUI to iperf as well called "jperf". I highly recommend iperf with jperf. We used it at my previous job and were able to do testing on "N" wireless.